# Talend Open Studio: ETL

Tags: etl, talend

so here's the thing, I tried to make a data warehouse ETL process (Extract, Transform, Load) with Talend Open Studio. In this ETL process, i used 3 table: cleaned_Student, cleaned_TeachingLearningProcess, cleaned_Province and i merge/join them using tMap. I've assigned the tables with key from each table. In tMap settings, i have set cleaned_TeachingLearningProcess and cleaned_Province to All Matches and Inner Join. But, this ETL process give me a 0 row. Can you please tell me where did I make a mistake? Sorry for my broken english and thankyou all in advance!

[ETL process picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlJWX.png)

[tMap picture(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIBVd.png)

[tMap picture(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOzzU.png)

desc tMap pic:
row 1 is cleaned_Student,
row 2 is  cleaned_TeachingLearningProcess
row 5 is cleaned_Province

Comment: Please can you add a picture showing how the tMap component is configured

Comment: @NickW I've added a tMap picture

Comment: I suggest that you use two tmaps sequentially to do this : in first tMap, join your main flow with cleaned_pbm, extract needed data to your output flow. then join your output flow with the other lookup, in a second tMap. This way you will know which of the lookup is causing problem.

Comment: okey thank you for your suggestion